# How to filter output of Java Applet Console in browser?

Tags: java, browser, applet, console

I am trying to debug my applet in browser and Java Console has been enabled.

Basically for every class two message like below gets printed. And I want to get rid of it.

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/applet/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFutureListener$2.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/applet/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFutureListener$2.class with proxy=DIRECT
```

Of course, I can copy-paste, save in a file, then apply filter and so on. Is there a way to disable these messages to get printed at all to console?

Comment: this seems like a useful [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/tracing_logging.html), but it would disable all network messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the only opportunity, which I have overlooked

---

```
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

**`0-5: set trace level to <n>`** can filter all network messages

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/tracing_logging.html